# Force factor extraction from a polynomial

Tags: polynomials, factorization

I have the following polynomial
$$27 m^7 + 117 m^6 s^{\frac{1}{2}} - 114 m^5 s - 273 m^4 s^{\frac{3}{2}} + 15 m^3 s^2 + 
91 m^2 s^{\frac{5}{2}} - 7 s^{\frac{7}{2}}$$
and I want to force Mathematica to extract some factors, for example I would like to write it as a product of $(s^{\frac{1}{2}}+3m)$ (obviously with some sort of rest). Is it possible? And if it is, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Have you seen [the documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialReduce.html) of `PolynomialReduce`? You will need to introduce some variable changes so you have polynomials, but should be doable.

Comment: Polynomials usually have integer exponents you know ;)

Comment: Yes but if you write x=s^(1/2) it's quite the same ;)

Comment: @FilippoCaleca I can factor your "polynomial" to `(3 m - x) (m + x) (9 m^5 + 33 m^4 x - 57 m^3 x^2 - 42 m^2 x^3 + 14 m x^4 + 7 x^5)` where `x^2==s` but I'm not sure what your goal.

Comment: First thing I would try is `Factor` (voting to close this because that seems to factor it just fine).

Answer (score 2):

```
poly = 27 m^7 + 117 m^6 s^(1/2) - 114 m^5 s - 273 m^4 s^(3/2) + 15 m^3 s^2 + 91 m^2 s^(5/2) - 7 s^(7/2);

Factor[PowerExpand[poly /. s -> x^2]] /. x -> s^(1/2)
```

> $\left(3 m-\sqrt{s}\right) \left(m+\sqrt{s}\right) \left(-42 m^2 s^{3/2}+33 m^4
>    \sqrt{s}-57 m^3 s+9 m^5+14 m s^2+7 s^{5/2}\right)$

Comment: One has to be careful when using `PowerExpand`, but if `fpoly` is the factored polynomial, `Simplify[fpoly==poly]` yields `True`, so this result is verified.